# phpcs require alternative syntax in html files

Tags: php-5.3, phpcs

I want to require alternative syntax in controle structure within html files , otherwise, throw error or warning if alternative syntax rules not been respected in whatever instruction .

Below is an example of alternative syntax that should be established:

```
<?php if (true === $var) : ?>
 <h3>Hello world</h3>
<?php else : ?>
<h3>Hello</h3>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Is there a phpcs sniff which deals with such requirements ? if not , how can we make a customized sniff to check for alternative syntax in html files ?

Comment: I'm not aware of any sniffs that check this. You can certainly write a custom one. You'd need to listen for scope openers like IF/FOREACH/FOR/WHILE etc, then check their scope_opener and see if it is a curly brace. If it is, it's not alternate syntax. Then you might also put a check in to only run that sniff if the filename ends in .tpl (or whatever extension your template files have).

Comment: Thank you for your advise @GregSherwood , I did exactly what you have told me , except checking filename type . in fact, i want execute this sniff in every file which contains html syntax (including php files which may contains html). Did you have ideas about this ?

Comment: If a file contains mixed PHP and HTML, you'll be able to listen for a T_INLINE_HTML token. If you see one of those, you know there is some HTML in that file. If you also find a T_OPEN_TAG then you know there is also PHP code in there.

Comment: any chance this new sniff got open-sourced? I'm also looking for something like that :)